# After Android Studio is updated, the project cannot be synchronized

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

After Android Studio is updated, the project cannot be synchronized, and the error message ”Failed to resolve: agconnect-core-1.0.0.300” is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Enter the following link in the address box of the browser and check whether the file can be downloaded.
   https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/huawei/agconnect/agconnect-core/1.0.0.300/agconnect-core-1.0.0.300.aar
2. If the download is successful, check whether a proxy is configured for Android Studio or Gradle on your network.
3. If the file can not be downloaded, check your network.